# Ubunut 18.04 failed to boot. [FAILED] Failed to start MySQL Community Server

Tags: ubuntu, boot, mysql, operating-systems, ubuntu-18.04

I am facing serious issue. My hard disk was extremely full that 0 bytes available. I tried to empty the trash bin but it hanged. I restarted the system. But it failed. It gives this messages:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Seee 'systemctl status mysql.service' for details.
```

The cursors is blinking but I can't type anything.

Is there any hope that I boot the system under sort of `last known good configurations` or `safe mode` like in Windows?

I made hardware test and the device is healthy. Please help me disable MySQL or boot my system I just need my data because lots of work there.

**EDIT:**

The device company can not help with data backup. They can only format and install the system. I need my data.

Comment: Did you trying to boot this OS from Live OS (boot from USB) and check what consume a lot of space? Check /var/log/ directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved by rebooting the system in the recover mode. 
To reach the recovery mode in Ubunut 18.04, click the left `Shift` bottom and `Esc`. Then you will get options, choose `Clean` which deletes some unnecessary files that can free up few hundreds of MBs. My main problem was full disk (0 Bytes available). 
After that, I could reboot successfully.